# ListView con kotlin y la libreria Piccaso

Tags: android, kotlin

Bueno quisiera usar la libreria Piccaso para cargar imagenes en un ListView pero al momento de cargar la imagen me genera un error no se como utlizar otra forma la imagen la cargo con la url de firebase

Model.kt
class Model (val title:String, val desc:String, val img:Int)

MyListAdapter.kt

```
class MyListAdapter (var mCtx:Context, var resource:Int, var items:List<Model>)
    :ArrayAdapter<Model>(mCtx, resource, items){
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

        val layoutInflater:LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx)
        val view:View = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, null)

        val imageView:ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        val textView:TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.titleTv)
        val textView2:TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.descTv)

        var mItems:Model = items[position]

        imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.resources.getDrawable(mItems.img))
        textView.text = mItems.title
        textView2.text = mItems.desc

        return view
    }
}

MainActivity.kt

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-bbefc.appspot.com/o/aaa.jpg?alt=media&token=44ead264-a661-43b8-8f27-2df0ba2276b0"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)
        var list = mutableListOf<Model>()

        list.add(Model("Habitacion para 2 personas", "Precio 150$", Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageView)))
//el error esta en la linea Piccaso


    }
}
```

Comment: Es importante agregues en tus preguntas que error obtienes, de esa forma puedes obtener una ayuda adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Al agregar las propiedades del objeto Model a la lista, añade ùnicamente el url de la imagen:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-bbefc.appspot.com/o/aaa.jpg?alt=media&token=44ead264-a661-43b8-8f27-2df0ba2276b0"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)
        var list = mutableListOf<Model>()

        //list.add(Model("Habitacion para 2 personas", "Precio 150$", Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageView)))

        list.add(Model("Habitacion para 2 personas", "Precio 150$", url))


    }
}
```

Dentro de tu clase `MyListAdapter` obtén la url y la cargas en el `ImageView` mediante `Picasso`:

```
class MyListAdapter (var mCtx:Context, var resource:Int, var items:List<Model>)
    :ArrayAdapter<Model>(mCtx, resource, items){
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

        val layoutInflater:LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx)
        val view:View = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, null)

        val imageView:ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        val textView:TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.titleTv)
        val textView2:TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.descTv)

        var mItems:Model = items[position]

        //imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.resources.getDrawable(mItems.img))

        //* Carga imagen usando Picasso.
        Picasso.get().load(mItems.img).into(imageView)

        textView.text = mItems.title
        textView2.text = mItems.desc

        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: ohhh muchisimas gracias